# ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist

Tags: python, pip, package, github-actions, pypi

I used the [`Upload Python Package`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva/actions/workflows/python-publish.yml) workflow on `GitHub` to upload the module stored in the [`repository`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva) to `PyPI`.

As you can see at the link above, I followed the tutorial given by [`packaging.python.org`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-the-package-files), to be more specific I used [`setup.py`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva/blob/main/setup.py) instead of `setup.cfg`.

---

Anyway an error occurred during the [`last deploy`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva/runs/6242472007?check_suite_focus=true), which gave me the following error:

```
Run python -m build
      python -m build
      shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
      env:
        pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.4/x64
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.4/x64/lib
    running egg_info
    creating src/classevivaAPI.egg-info
    writing src/classevivaAPI.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/classevivaAPI.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/classevivaAPI.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'src/classevivaAPI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: package directory 'src/classevivaAPI' does not exist
    * Creating venv isolated environment...
    * Installing packages in isolated environment... (selenium>=4.1.3, setuptools>=42)
    * Getting dependencies for sdist...
 


ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

In particular I was wondering what does the following line mean:

> `ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist`

---

Have you ever had the same problem? Do you know how to solve it and upload my package? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with

```
package_dir={'':"src"},
packages=find_packages("src")
```

I also faced similar issues, but was able to fix it by correcting the package_dir.

Below is my repo, where I have done the same.
[Hello World Python Package](https://github.com/mahesh-maximus/helloworld-pyp/blob/main/setup.py)

Comment: How did you correct it?

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate? It doesn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had that problem and fixed it by using "setuptools" in the pyproject.toml
and setup.py files, instead of "hatchling".

Answer (score 0):

wrap your package in a folder, for instance, src.
so instead of having only `my_package`, you should have something like `src\my_package` in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I was attempting to include (DataBricks) notebooks as modules; something about the format of this file type kicks this error.

I resolved by ensuring that I include only straight python files as modules.

Secondarily, when using cloud compute in DataBricks, a shared compute cluster will generate the same error - a single-user cluster will work without error.